# SSRS - Open hyperlink using javascript

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to open an url in ssrs.When I try directly ="http://www.google.com" it works.

I'm using placeholder properties - Action - GoToURL

="javascript:void(window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank'))" is not working.
I have tried both IE and chrome.Any help is appreaciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have not added much info ti's hard to tell what "doesn't work". However as a guide you use this format... This assumes the URL is stored in a field.

```
="javascript:void(window.open('" & TRIM(Fields!URL.Value) & "','_blank'))"
```

I have used this regularly with no problems. This will only work once the report is deployed (it won't work from Visual Studio or Report Builder)

Comment: In my report ,the hyperlink is not opening a new page/tab..but giving the link directly works and opens in new tab.I would like to use the link directly instead of storing it in a field.Is that possible to do that?Thanks!

Comment: Check is javascript is enabled in the browser or try from another PC. I can't think of any other reason why this would not work. This link will do a quick test https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/is-javascript-enabled