# PDF inside SSRS won't open in new tab

Tags: asp.net, pdf, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I have an ASP.NET web page loading an SSRS which has a hyperlink to a PDF inside the report.  When the user clicks the pdf hyperlink, I need it to open in a new tab.  Currently, it opens in the same tab. After reviewing the pdf, when the user clicks the back arrow, they return to the SSRS and all of their selected parameters are now gone.  I need to know if it's possible to open the given pdf in a new tab? Is this a syntax issue or just a limitation of the design (a pdf in a report in a web page)?  I am also open to an alternate scenario in which the user reviews their pdf and then click the back button and their selected params are still binding, how could I do that?

I'm confident I'm in the right spot.  I'm inside of the field that has the pdf link, then textbox expressions, then action, then expression. My initial code:
`=IIF(Fields!tableValue.Value Is Nothing,"",IIF(Fields!tableValue.Value  Like "*pdf","https://website.com/websiteuploads/deliveries/" &Fields!tableValue.Value,""))`

I've tried this code expecting the pdf to open in another tab, but the impacted column returns this error: contains a colon or a line terminator. The definition of the report is invalid. An error occurred during local report processing.

`=IIF(Fields!tableValue.Value Is Nothing,"",IIF(Fields!tableValue.Value  Like "*pdf","https://website.com/websiteuploads/deliveries/" &Fields!tableValue.Value&rs:Command=Render&rc:LinkTarget=_blank,""))`

Comment: take a look at this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60725469